# Как сделать разделение item без title?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

> Простое удаление самого комментария не помогает, т.к. остаётся большое промежуток. Пробовал добавлять group, удалять title с комментом и menu, но пропадает строка разделения. Что и как прописать?

[image: Необходимо, чтобы было разделение, но без комментариев]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо добавить `group` для `menu`, вместо `item`, а также присвоить группам разные `id`.

```
<group android:id="@+id/my_id">
<!-- Divider will appear above this item -->
<item ... />
```

Из [источника](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605286/navigationview-how-to-insert-divider-without-subgroup):

> [NavigationView] Создаёт разделитель всякий раз, когда `group id` меняется